# How to make this python regex work correctly

Tags: python, regex

I need to validate a number with Python regex, but it is not working.

The code below is a library that is being used by another file. At this point, I am only trying to make the input be the only numbers between 13 and 19 digits. The range works just fine, but when I put a letter into the input, it prints it, instead of giving the "Invalid" string output:

```
"""
Credit card number validation and provider check
"""
import re

def card_range(cardNumber):
    """
    Checks the credit card number length
    """
    if len(cardNumber) < 13:
        return "Invalid"
    if len(cardNumber) >  19:
        return "Invalid" 
    
    pattern = re.compile("[0-9]+")
    if not pattern.match(cardNumber):
        return "Invalid"
    return cardNumber
```

Answer (score 7):

You need boundary markers in your regex.  But, I would just use a single pattern here:

```py
def card_range(cardNumber):
    return re.search(r'^[0-9]{13,19}$', cardNumber)
```

By the way, regular expressions for the major credit card providers are readily available, e.g. [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check using the `isnumeric` method if the string appears to be a number? Seems like it'll be faster than the regex solution, since we just want to check for a number anyway.

```py
def card_range(cardNumber):
    """
    Checks the credit card number length
    """
    if not cardNumber.isnumeric():
        return 'Invalid! I need only NUMBERZ!'

    if not 13 <= len(cardNumber) <= 19:
        return "Invalid! The length check FAILED!"

    return True

# Invalid! The length check FAILED!
print(card_range('1234567'))

# Invalid! I need only NUMBERZ!
print(card_range('a'))

# True
print(card_range('112233445566778899'))

# Invalid! I need only NUMBERZ!
print(card_range('1122334455x6778899'))
```

Comment: Why import `re` when you don't use it?

Comment: this is a prime example of copypasta .. my bad there

Comment: I just want to use regex because it is a college project, and the professor is expecting us to use it. I will ask her if it is ok to use something more "advanced". Thanks for the hint!

Comment: ah, no worries. In that case the regex solution should be perfect for this use case.